# Открытие файла из директории

Tags: filestream, android, файлы

Всем привет! Решил написать для себя текстовый редактор под андроид и столкнулся с такой проблемой. Я хочу сделать `OpenFileDialog`, то есть, он уже есть, просто я не могу открыть конкретный файл.

А вот вызов в `Main`:

```
OpenFileDialog fileDialog = new
OpenFileDialog(this)
                        .setFilter(".*\\.txt")
                        .setOpenDialogListener(new
OpenFileDialog.OpenDialogListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void OnSelectedFile(String fileName) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
fileName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        });
                fileDialog.show();
```

Теперь надо написать метод по открытию файла и вызвать в `OnSelectedFile`?
Просто я, как ни старался, не хочет. Я новичёк, так что не судите строго)

а я не говорю что мне нужно готовое решение я в самом конце спросил как действовать, но так как ничего никто не ответил я уже сам всё сделал создав отдельный метод который как я и думал надо вызвать в OnSelectedFile что я и сделал и всё получилось.

Comment: @OneXeor, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось. @OneXeor, Пожалуйста, оформляйте вопросы согласно правилам сообщества, иначе они будут удаляться. 
Пожалуйста, оставьте только часть кода, который необходим для решения задачи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ExFilePicker](https://github.com/bartwell/ExFilePicker)

[aFileChooser](https://github.com/iPaulPro/aFileChooser)